# Check if a GeoJSON source is present in mapbox viewport

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a map with several layers of GeoJSON each with their own unique layer name:

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  center: [-97.5651505, 37.89549,],
  zoom: 4
});

var sources = {
  'ord': 'chicago',
  'pit': 'pittsburgh',
  'atl': 'atlanta'
};

map.on('load', function () {
  for (var s in sources) {

    map.addSource(s, { type: 'geojson', data: `/geojson/${s}.json` });
    map.addLayer({
      'id': sources[s],
      'type': 'fill',
      'source': s,
      'layout': {
        'visibility': 'visible'
      },
      'paint': {
        'fill-color': '#088',
        'fill-opacity': 0.5
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I would like to check if a user has zoomed in past zoom level 13 evaluate if any of these three layers is in the viewport. If it is I'll take action to add a button to the overlay. However, I'm having issues finding any documentation other than leaflet on how to check if a layer is inside the viewport. I've found some mention of markers that that doesn't seem to apply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with [`queryRenderedFeatures`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#queryrenderedfeatures) which returns an array of features rendered within a given bounding box. However, if you omit the bounding box argument, `queryRenderedFeatures` will query within the entire viewport. You can also use the `options.layers` argument to limit your query to specific layers to avoid getting a bunch of features that are in the underlying style (for example, streets and lakes). You can do this query in a `zoomend` event listener to achieve your desired outcome. Putting it all together would look something like this:

```
map.on('zoomend', () => {
  if (map.getZoom() > 13) {
    const visibleFeatures = map.queryRenderedFeatures(null, {layers: ['ord', 'pit', 'atl']});
    // if none of the layers are visible, visibleFeatures will be an empty array
    if (visibleFeatures.length) {
      // figure out which layers are showing and add your button
    }
  }
});
```